# Microsoft Azure (SQL database > Query editor)

Tags: sql-server

```
INSERT INTO Table_name (column1 <varchar datatype>, column2 <varcahr datatype>, 
                        column3 <numeric datatype>, column4 <DATE datatype>)
```

For example:

```
VALUES ('TRP040', 'Ford Magnum', 27070,
To_date('12/03/2014', 'dd/mm/yyyy'));
```

Result : Eror

> Failed to execute query. Error: 'To_date' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Could anyone can answer what is wrong with "To_Date" is not recognized built-in function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option is `Set DateFormat DMY`

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (column1 varchar(50),column2 varchar(50),column3 int,column4 date)

Set DateFormat DMY
Insert Into @YourTable values
('TRP040', 'Ford Magnum', 27070,'12/03/2014')

Select * from @YourTable
```

**New Record**

```
column1 column2     column3 column4
TRP040  Ford Magnum 27070   2014-03-12
```

**However**, I would rather `TRY_CONVERT(date,'12/03/2014',103)`.  This would return generate a NULL if the conversion fails and NOT throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message is clearly says

> 'To_date' is not a recognized built-in function name.

SQL Server has no `To_date()` function. You have to use `convert()` or `cast()`

```
select CONVERT(date, '12/03/2014', 103)
```

Use always ISO/ANSI Standard date format `YYYYMMDD` or `YYYY-MM-DD`